# How can I pan a google vrview image around 360 degrees automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-vr

My vr `div` is setup simply as follows:

`<div style="pointer-events:auto;" class="html-embed w-embed w-iframe">
      <div id="vrview"></div>
</div>`

The javascript initializing the vr:

```
  window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad)
  function onVrViewLoad() {
     var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
     image: 'image',
    is_stereo: false, width:w ,height:h,
    default_yaw: 55,
    });

  }
```

The image loads fine and when i change the `default_yaw` the center view changes as well. Is there a method to auto-rotate the image 360 degrees without dragging the image with the mouse?